# Visual Studio on Mac Book Pro

Tags: macos, visual-studio-2010

I just bought a MacBookPro (13", 250HD, and 4GB Ram) because, among other things, I would like to write iPhone Apps.
I need, anyway, to use VS2010 so I think about installing Sun Virtual Box (I've used and I like it) to run Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2010 and SqlExpress2008.

Have you tried it? How many RAM GBs should I reserve for Windows? If I assign 2GB to Windows, will my Mac run fine with the remaining 2GB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run Windows 7 and VS 2010 in VMWare Fusion on my Macbook. It has 2GB of RAM, and I've allocated 1GB to the virtual machine. It can be a bit slow at times, but not massively

Answer (score 1):

I've been running Windows XP and Visual Studio in a virtual machine on my MacBook Pro for about a year. I've found that allocating 2GB to Windows and 2 to OS X seems to work well. Everything runs smoothly as long as you don't try to run too much in the host OS (don't try running Mail, iTunes, Firefox, etc all at the same time). I've not run into any trouble running a slew of apps in the VM.

All that being said, I've not tried it running Windows 7 and with it's higher RAM requirements I wouldn't be surprised if you ran into issues.